# Can I disable domain login with PIN in W10?

Tags: windows-10, pin, windows-hello

We are currently using login with fingerprint in our domain but I would like to disable PIN login for users. So they can use only fingerprint or password. Is there a way how to disable login with PIN?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable Domain Users to Sign in with PIN via Group policy:

> 1.Open the Local Group Policy Editor.
>
> 2.In the left pane of Local Group Policy Editor, navigate to the location below.
>
> **Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon**
>
> 3.In the right pane of Logon in Local Group Policy Editor, double click on the **Turn on convenience PIN sign-in** policy to edit it.
>
> 4.Select **Disabled**, click on OK.
>
> 5.When finished, you can close the Local Group Policy Editor, and **restart the computer** to apply.

For more details, you can refer to the following article:

[How to Enable or Disable Domain Users to Sign in with PIN to Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/80520-enable-disable-domain-users-sign-pin-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Hello @Candy, thank you for your answer. But when I disable this settings I can't set up windows hello (fingerprint and face). I would like to use fingerprint and face but just block login with PIN. Do u got my point?

Comment: Now I got it. It seems you have to set up a PIN code then you can enable the fingerprint authentication. See the following article:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-why-pin-is-better-than-password#why-do-you-need-a-pin-to-use-biometrics

Comment: So it is not possible to have fingerprint without PIN. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, based on my research, it is not possible to have fingerprint without PIN.